# Insert/remove component to/from DOM

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use HostBinding on my custom component:

**app-form-error.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-form-error[form]',
    templateUrl: 'app-form-error.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app-form-error.component.css'],
    host: {
        '[ngIf]': 'form.errors'
    },
    inputs: ['form']
})
export class AppFormErrorComponent {
    form: FormGroup;
}
```

**app-form.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppFormErrorComponent } from './app-form-error/app-form-error.component';

const APP_FORM_DIRECTIVES = [
    AppFormErrorComponent
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        APP_FORM_DIRECTIVES
    ],
    exports: [
        APP_FORM_DIRECTIVES
    ]
})
export class AppFormModule {

}
```

But I'm getting following error:

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'app-form-error'.

How can I fix it?

P.S. I'm using Angular 2 RC6

[UPDATE]

OK I understand now that HostBinding isn't an option. But I'm still curious how to implement conditional inserting.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough on the expected behaviour. Is the component supposed to add/remove *itself*?

Comment: @estus, yes it is.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense then. How can the component do something if it doesn't exist in DOM? What you're asking for is probably achievable with ngIf in component's template.